# UrlRewriteFilter won't redirect URLs below root

Tags: tomcat, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I want to set up a 302 redirect.  I am serving a webapp from `apache-tomcat-7.0.30/webapps/myapp`.  I am trying to use Tuckey's **UrlRewriteFilter**, but haven't been successful in getting redirects triggered.  Right now I am trying to get something, anything to redirect.  Here's what I have in `myapp/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml`:

```xml
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
       <from>/myapp(.*)$</from>
       <to type="redirect">http://www.example.com</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

The only thing I've successfully gotten to redirect is:

```xml
<rule match-type="wildcard">
<from>**</from>
<to type="redirect">http://www.example.com</to>
```

However, that's not too useful.  I have tried every possible combination of slashes, no slashes, redirect, temporary-redirect, one star, two stars, to no avail.  Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?